# List View Filter by Filtered Lookup field

Tags: list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part

There is an XSLT List View web part and I want to filter data by [Filtered Lookup](http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) field. What is a proper way to do this? When I click "Edit the current view" of web part and filter by this field it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with the "Filtered Lookup" add-in, but it interested me, and when viewing the page you linked, I noticed that it appears that you are supposed to set the filter on the Field Edit page for your Filtered Lookup field; not by setting a filter on the current view, as you would with an OOTB field type.

I attempted to insert a screenshot, but apparently I need at least 10 points to insert a picture, so you're out of luck!

If you go here:
http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/

and scroll to the bottom of the page, it shows 2 examples of the types of filters you can set on the Field Edit page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did this help you at all?